# C# - Is there any additional advantage to throw an exception immediately after input argument validations in the method

Tags: c#, validation, exception, methods, arguments

I understand that **GetInfo1** method from the below provides better readability. But is there any other difference (e.g. run-time execution) between the below two methods i.e. throwing an exception immediately at the start of the method compared to the end of the method?

```
public string GetInfo1(string name) {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(name));

        var info = GetInfoByName(name);
        return info;
    }

public string GetInfo2(string name) {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) {
            var info = GetInfoByName(name);
            return info;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(name));
    }
```

Comment: Note that throwing `ArgumentNullException` for a non-null argument is pretty bad form. If I call `GetInfo1("")` I might expect `ArgumentException`, but not `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: Agree @JonSkeet but added the pseudo code just being curious to find the difference. I will update it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the GetInfo1 approach is more flexible and provides better extensibility. You can add code(more if statements) to validate more cases without deleting anything.

I mean generally. If you just want to check for null or white spaces and you're sure that you won't validate more cases in the future, then both approaches are fine.

Also, keep in mind that exceptions should be used in exceptional cases. It's pretty common for a user to forget to fill a field or enter a white space by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing at the start means you validate ALL information before you do anything with it. It also means that code doesn't need to run that isn't needed.

It can also be tidier than having lots of `if` statements checking values if you're checking everything at the start (this is especially effective when you could end up nesting lots of if's).

It's also worth noting that things like Resharper suggest you exit from a method ASAP. So `GetInfo1` is the recommended way as far as suggested best practices go.

So, in short exiting at the start is better because:

1. It's more readable
2. It follows suggested best practices
3. Avoids lots of unnecessary if statements throughout the method
4. Code doesn't run that doesn't need to run.

Comment: I believe it is easier to reason about the code when you exit early.

Comment: @CallumLinington I didn't mention that in my post as he already stated he knows it's more readable but I've added it in for clarity.

Comment: @webnoob I suppose the code which is inside if block will not run even in case of GetInfo2 since the if condition will evaluate to false but just that the throw statement is located after n number of statements.

Comment: @SivaramK You're correct but this is a very simple case. Most examples would be more complex and have more data to check in which case it would soon get messy.